# MongoDB group query based on input

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to create top 10 product list based on postType = "buy". My logic is a count postType = "buy" and sort the top 10 products from the logs collection. Here are my sample log collections.

```
[
    {
        "_id": "633dc5b761ff04e7ae8e8c0f",
        "postType": "buy",
        "product": "3",
    },
 {
        "_id": "633dc5b761ff04e7ae8e8c0f",
        "postType": "view",
        "product": "4",
    },
 {
        "_id": "633dc5b761ff04e7ae8e8c0f",
        "postType": "buy",
        "product": "2",
    },
 {
        "_id": "633dc5b761ff04e7ae8e8c0f",
        "postType": "view",
        "product": "2",
    },
 {
        "_id": "633dc5b761ff04e7ae8e8c0f",
        "postType": "share",
        "product": "3",
    },
 {
        "_id": "633dc5b761ff04e7ae8e8c0f",
        "postType": "buy",
        "product": "2",
    },
 {
        "_id": "633dc5b761ff04e7ae8e8c0f",
        "postType": "buy",
        "product": "2",
    },
 {
        "_id": "633dc5b761ff04e7ae8e8c0f",
        "postType": "share",
        "product": "2",
    },
 {
        "_id": "633dc5b761ff04e7ae8e8c0f",
        "postType": "buy",
        "product": "1",
    },
 {
        "_id": "633dc5b761ff04e7ae8e8c0f",
        "postType": "buy",
        "product": "1",
    },
 {
        "_id": "633dc5b761ff04e7ae8e8c0f",
        "postType": "viewvideo",
        "product": "1",
    },
 {
        "_id": "633dc5b761ff04e7ae8e8c0f",
        "postType": "viewvideo",
        "product": "2",
    },
 {
        "_id": "633dc5b761ff04e7ae8e8c0f",
        "postType": "viewvideo",
        "product": "3",
    },
 {
        "_id": "633dc5b761ff04e7ae8e8c0f",
        "postType": "buy",
        "product": "4",
    },
 {
        "_id": "633dc5b761ff04e7ae8e8c0f",
        "postType": "buy",
        "product": "5",
    }
]
```

My expected output is:

```
 [{"product":1, "count":2},{"product":2, "count":3},{"product":3, "count":1}, 
   {"product":4, "count":1},{"product":5, "count":1}
 ]
```

I tried the following code, but it is not working.

```
 {
        $project: {
          _id: 0,
          list: { $setEquals: ["$postType", "buy"] }
        }
      }
```

I just inserted 4 products but it will be 10 actually.

Comment: Grouping in MongoDB usually involves the `$group` stage. The documentation contains a number of examples, [this one in particular](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#group-by-item-having) may be relevant for your situation. Should help you get started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { postType: "buy" } }, // filter on postType = "buy"
  {
    $group: {                      // group and count
      _id: "$product",
      count: { $count: {} }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {                   // some cosmetic
      product: "$_id",
      count: 1,
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GpuhfhbJaq2)

Comment: Thank you , let me try

Comment: Is there any option to populate product collection data based on the product id ? product id will be mongodb object id.

Comment: Not clear what you mean, sorry.

Comment: Is it possible to count other postType in the same query? like my expected output now is  ```[{"product":1, "count":2, "shareButtonCount":4, viewCount":4},{"product":2, "count":3, shareButtonCount":4, viewCount":4},{"product":3, "count":1, shareButtonCount":4, viewCount":4}, 
   {"product":4, "count":1, shareButtonCount":4, viewCount":4},{"product":5, "count":1, shareButtonCount":2, viewCount":4}
 ] ```

Comment: No idea what you mean. Perhaps replace `_id: "$product"` by `_id: {product: "$product", postType: "$postType"}` and skip the `$match`. Maybe open a new question for it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74220132/mongodb-generate-group-query-based-on-the-keyword created .